# How do I empty the trash in Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, trash

I have been deleting files on my machine for several months now. The deleted files are likely to be using up considerable space on my HD. I want to empty trash, but cant fond out how to do it.

I located a folder .user/local/trash (or similar name), and when I deleted the files in that folder, the contents got doubled because the files I selected and deleted were added again to that list. This getting beyond being simply irritating - I have looked online and unbelievably, I cant find anything that shows how to empty the trash *even on the Ubuntu site) - WHY??

BTW, I am NOT interested in recovering deleted files (at least for now). All the documentation I have come accross is just about restoring files.

ALL I WANT TO DO IS TO DELETE FILES - now, does anybody know how to do that, or am I going to pointed (yet again), to a question/link about restoring files that were accidentally deleted?

Answer (score 6):

Try `~/.local/share/Trash/files`
They moved the trash folder in 9.10 for some reason.

Comment: ok, I can see "millions" of files in that folder (FINALLY!). Now how do I delete them?. I dont want to rm -rf without knowing what I'm doing. Also, in case there is a file I want to "undelete"(i.e. recover), how do I do that?. last but not the least, is it normal to manage the trash can by the cmd line only?. I thought there must be a simple trash can manager icon somewhere?

Comment: @morpheous trash is where you put things you might want to 'undelete' - it you empty the trash, it is gone forever.

Comment: Ah, thanks Dave and Tony, this is one more thing I need to check when I shift to `9.10`.

Comment: @DaveParillo: yes, my question was - if I notice there is something in the trash I want to undelete, how do I undelete it BEFORE emptying the trash - is it simply a case of 'mv' ing the file to another folder, or is the file somehow tainted once its been in the bin, so special recovery tools required?

Comment: @morpheous - Do not try to use `cp`, `rm` or `mv` to manage your trash.  You will be unhappy.  In nautilus, right-click on a file or folder in the trash and select 'Restore'

Answer (score 5):

Open Nautilus, the graphical file manager. In your 'Places' frame on the top left, you will see a 'Trash' icon. Open it, then select the 'Empty' button, or just right click the icon and select 'empty' from there. My apologies if you're looking for a way to do this though the command line.

Comment: @Nerdfest: thanks for the info. Either cmd line or GUI would be fine. Incidentally, I don't have the trash icon in ANY of my menus - this was the first thing I was looked for (coming from a windows background)

Comment: @morpheous - it's not in a menu - it's in the side pane.  Select *View -> Side Pane* or press "F9" to open it.

Comment: wasn't quite where you said (I think I have a different GUI), but I managed to find it (bottom right on the 'status bar'). Thanks